# How to make citations?

Tags: bibliographies

I have noted that sites like *Wikipedia* allow you to make "indexed" citations using the html tag `<ref>` and `</ref>`. As the following example:

`<ref> Robert B. Tomer, ''Getting the most out of vacuum tubes'', Howard W. Sams, Indianapolis, USA 1960, Library of Congress card no. 60-13843, available on the Intenet Archive.  Chapter 3.  </ref>`

Next to the text (not begining a bibliography environment or anything). And even something similar happens when you put external links in the questions here in stackexchange.

What Im looking for is something like that, in such a way that whenever I type information I can cite something with all the information required as shown before with the *Wikipedia* example, and then add additional \bibitems if required. I want the citations to appear in order as well (like [1], [2], [3], ...), but I also want to decide if I want the additional citations before the ones that are trough the text, or after:

```
[1] Additional.
[2] Additional.
[3] InTextCitation.
[4] InTextCitation.
[5] Additional.
[6] Additional.
```

Comment: Isn't having all references in one place (a `.bib` file) a better way to manage them?

Comment: @egreg I want to make it simpler, I am creating the reference at the end then I compile and come back to edit the place where I had the reference and paste the reference with a `\textsuperscript{[number]}`, when I finish my work. But your idea can might work if I can create a file from the document and save the citations as shown for wikipedia, then at the end I'll just call the file with the citations in the order that they are in the file.

Comment: This kind of seems exactly why BibTeX/BibLaTeX were created... so you don't have to go back through and number them when you finish.  As it is, why don't you use a footnote or endnote?

Comment: No, the footnotes are just that, footnotes, I won't use them for citations, according to my work I would have to delete the Bibliography if I follow your advice (almost all the bibliography will be cited inline).

Comment: What reference management software do you use? (I use BibDesk) What's wrong with simply drop/drag citations from the software? If you really like, you can use the full citation in the citation key. The system you're explaining would not allow you to cite the same source twice. And would generally hinder workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for two things:

1. Embedding bibliographical information at arbitrary points in a document. I think this goal is misguided.  By embedding your bibliographical information throughout your document, in anything but the most trivial documents you will make it *harder* to figure out what you have already cited, not to mention make it harder to find.  (I assume you are imagining a very simple bibliography in a very simple document, but that simply indicates that you are asking for an inflexible system that won't scale well generally.)  More importantly, however, I can't solve this problem for you...
2. The ability to only `\cite` some items from a fuller bibliography that appears in the order you wish.  This is trivial to do with either `thebibliography` environment, with `natbib`, and with `biblatex`.  Basically all you need to do is use a `\nocite{*}` at the start of your document.

All the following examples will print the bibliographical entries in the order they appear in either the `.bib` file or in the `thebibliography` environment.  And of course it will be much easier to find these entries because they are all located in the same place/file

### Using `natbib`

```
% normally this would be (and can be) an external file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{jackson91,
    author    = {Jackson, John David},
    title     = {Classical Electrodynamics},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
    address  = {New Jersey, USA},
    edition  = {3},
    year      = {1991}
}

@book{jackson92,
    author    = {Jackson, John David},
    title     = {Classical Electrodynamics},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
    address  = {New Jersey, USA},
    edition  = {3},
    year      = {1992}
}

@book{jackson93,
    author    = {Jackson, John David},
    title     = {Classical Electrodynamics},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
    address  = {New Jersey, USA},
    edition  = {3},
    year      = {1993}
}

@book{jackson94,
    author    = {Jackson, John David},
    title     = {Classical Electrodynamics},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Inc.},
    address  = {New Jersey, USA},
    edition  = {3},
    year      = {1994}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

I only mention the book from 1992 here~\cite{jackson92}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

### Using `biblatex`

```
% keep the same filecontents environment
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

I only mention the book from 1992 here~\cite{jackson92}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### Just for completeness, the unwanted solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Vaccum tubes~\cite{tomer}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[1]{companion} Michel Goossens, Franck Mittelbach and
  Alexander Samarin, \emph{The \LaTeX{} Companion}, Addison Wesley,
  1993.

\bibitem[2]{tomer} Robert B. Tomer, ``Getting the most out of vacuum
  tubes'', Howard W. Sams, Indianapolis, USA 1960, Library of Congress
  card no.\ 60--13843, available on the Intenet Archive. Chapter 3.

\bibitem[3]{lamport} Leslie Lamport, \emph{\LaTeX: A Document
    Preparation System}, Addison Wesley, 1997.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really close to the "unwanted solution" but it also involves the first thing you say I am asking for, embedding bibliographical information in arbitrary points. If you find how to do it one day I will appreciate it.